# Correction using error file in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have two text files. File_1 has huge data in 100 columns(formatted) and file_2 has mistakes in data entry, has 20 columns and first 15 are same format as data and last 5 contains text like "ACCNT","ADDSS" etc.
file_1 format is as follows

```
15382987019547317994113................(100 columns)
```

file_2 format is as follows

```
153829870195473ACCNT
```

What i have tried is

```
program rem_err
     implicit none
     character * 20 record
     character * 15 match, mat_dat
     character *5 element,replace
     character *80 data1 
     integer::i
     open (9,status='old',file='file_1.txt'
     open (10,status='old',file='file_2.txt'
      open (11,status='new',file='out.txt'

read (10,1,end=15)record
record(1:15)=match
record(16:20)=element

do 4 i=1,100000
read(9,5,end=15) mat_dat,replace,data1
    if(mat_dat.eq.match)then
         if (element=ACCNT)replace='*****)
         if (element=ADDSS)replace='     '
    write(11,5)mat_dat,replace,data1
else 
    write(11,5)mat_dat,replace,data1
endif
4 continue
    goto 2
1 format(a20)
5 format(a15,a5,a80)
15 stop
end program rem_err
```

How to correct file_1 using information from file_2?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Also note that Fortran 90 is extremely old and almost never used. Fortran 95 fixed aeveral problema in Fortran 90 and there are many modern revisions ending with Fortran 2018.

Comment: Please tell us more about your code you pasted. What does it do? Why are you not happy with it? Does it not do what you need? Are there any errors? Or is the result wrong? What exactly happens?

Comment: What are the variables `ACCNT` and `ADDSS`? Should these be strings (`'ACCNT'` and `'ADDSS'`)? Also, should `'*****)` be `'*****'`?

Comment: That means i should stop doing fortran 90 and start using fortran 95,right? Actually I'm very new to programming. i have tried the code to find  problematic element using error's file(file_2) and make appropriate corrections in the main file(file_1). code ive written simply writes file_1 to output file. hope this help.

Comment: @veryreverie..ACCNT and ADDSS from file_2  tells that file_1 is having wrong values for ACCNT and ADDSS fields. so program must to corrections in corresponding fields from file_1 and rewrite it. hope this may be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to resolve my problem..